# Firebase Transactions - Is this correct?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

So I've been looking around and there are lots of people doing Firebase Transactions and they are all different. All I want to do is just add 1 to a counter and what iv got works perfectly but I want to check that I am doing it properly because my way was a lot simpler than their docs.

Cheers is advance! :)

```
 database.child("stories").child(articleKey).runTransactionBlock({ (currentData:FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
            if var post = currentData.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                var likeCount = post["storyLikes"] as? Int ?? 0
                likeCount += 1
                post["storyLikes"] = likeCount as AnyObject?
                currentData.value = post

                return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }
            //Abort like if there was a problem
            return FIRTransactionResult.abort()
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks good to me, as long as you're happy with the logic.

Your current logic is only an update - if there is no existing post you will abort the transaction (`currentData.value` will be null).

You remove 1 from the `likeCount` rather than add as you mention in the description.

The version you have certainly works, but you may want to implement [`runTransaction:andCompletionBlock`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)runTransactionBlock:andCompletionBlock:) which lets you log errors, especially when debugging/testing.

Comment: Thank you! Ah yes, this was the unlike logic that I posted, whoops! When the article is created it sets the default like counter to 0 so it won't abort the transaction. I did see there was a completion block that I could use but I'm still tossing up if I need it! But thank you!